# PHP pass second argument into function

Tags: php, arguments

I have a function like this:

```
function myfunc(arg1=false, arg2=false){
    //some code here......
}
```

If I only want to pass arg1 into the function, I can write like this `myfunc("arg1 only variable")`. But how can I pass only arg2 into the function?

Thank you.

Comment: myfunc(false,$arg);

Comment: There's not way (currently) in php to skip a parameter, but there was some chatter about it on the php-internals mailing list, see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/skipparams

Comment: @Deepu Did you miss the sentence, "But how can I pass only arg2 into the function?" Perhaps it slipped your mind that `false, $arg` is two, separate arguments.

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
  myfunc(false, $arg2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of the following would be legal calls to your function:-

```
myfunc();
myfunc(true, true);
myfunc(true, null);
myfunc(null, true);
myfunc(null, null);
```